# VNFaceObservation BoundingBox Not Scaling In Portrait Mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, apple-vision

For reference, this stems from a question in the **Vision API**.  I am working to use **Vision** to detect faces in an image via a `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`, which is successfully functioning in terms of determining the correct number of faces in an image and providing the `boundingBox` for each face.

My trouble is that due to my `UIImageView` (which holds the `UIImage` in question) is using a `.scaleAspectFit` content mode, I am having immense difficulty in properly drawing the bounding box in portrait mode (things work great in landscape).

Here's my code;

```
func detectFaces(image: UIImage) {

    let detectFaceRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in
        if let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
            for faceObservation in results {
                let boundingRect = faceObservation.boundingBox

                let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -self.mainImageView.frame.size.height)
                let translate = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: self.mainImageView.frame.size.width, y: self.mainImageView.frame.size.height)
                let facebounds = boundingRect.applying(translate).applying(transform)

                let mask = CAShapeLayer()
                var maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer]()
                mask.frame = facebounds

                mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                mask.cornerRadius = 10
                mask.opacity = 0.3
                mask.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
                mask.borderWidth = 2.0

                maskLayer.append(mask)
                self.mainImageView.layer.insertSublayer(mask, at: 1)
            }
         }

    let vnImage = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image.cgImage!, options: [:])
    try? vnImage.perform([detectFaceRequest])

}
```

This is the end result of what I'm seeing, note that the boxes are correct in their **X** position, but largely inaccurate in their **Y** position when in portrait.

** Incorrect Placement In Portrait**
[image: Incorrect Placement In Portrait]

** Correct Placement In Landscape**
[image: Correct Placement In Landscape]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VNFaceObservation` bounding box are normalised to processed image. From documentation.

> The bounding box of detected object. The coordinates are normalized to
>   the dimensions of the processed image, with the origin at the image's
>   lower-left corner.

So you can use a simple calculation to find the correct size/frame for detected face like below.

```
let boundingBox = observation.boundingBox
let size = CGSize(width: boundingBox.width * imageView.bounds.width,
                  height: boundingBox.height * imageView.bounds.height)
let origin = CGPoint(x: boundingBox.minX * imageView.bounds.width,
                     y: (1 - observation.boundingBox.minY) * imageView.bounds.height - size.height)
```

then you can form the `CAShapeLayer` rect like below

`layer.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)`

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great for what I was after.  I just couldn't get the math right, but your guidance got me in the right place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide correct orientation to the CIImage, while sending to process and detect faces. As mentioned by @Pawel Chmiel in his [blog post](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/face-and-faces-landmarks-detection-using-vision-framework-in-ios-11) that:

> What is important here is that we need to provide the right orientation, because face detection is really sensitive at this point, and rotated image may cause no results.

```
 let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: attachments as! [String : Any]?)

 //leftMirrored for front camera
 let ciImageWithOrientation = ciImage.applyingOrientation(Int32(UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored.rawValue))
```

> For the front camera, we have to use leftMirrored orientation