# Face detection swift vision kit

Tags: face-detection, vision, ios11, swift4

I am trying Vision kit for iOS 11. I can use Vision and I can find boundbox values face. But I don't know how can I draw a rectangle using this points. I hope so my question is clear.

Comment: What have you done till now and what do you want to do from now? Please show by code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope you were able to use `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` and able to detect faces. To show rectangle boxes there are lots of ways to achieve it. But simplest one would be using `CAShapeLayer` to draw layer on top your image for each face you detected.

Consider you have `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` like below

```
let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { [unowned self] request, error in
            if let error = error {
                // somthing is not working as expected
            }
            else {
                //  we got some face detected
                self.handleFaces(with: request)
            }
        }
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])
        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
        }
        catch {
           // catch exception if any
        }
```

You can implement a simple method called `handleFace` for each face detected and use `VNFaceObservation` property to draw a `CAShapeLayer`.

```
func handleFaces(with request: VNRequest) {
        imageView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { layer in
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else {
            return
        }
        observations.forEach { observation in
            let boundingBox = observation.boundingBox
            let size = CGSize(width: boundingBox.width * imageView.bounds.width,
                              height: boundingBox.height * imageView.bounds.height)
            let origin = CGPoint(x: boundingBox.minX * imageView.bounds.width,
                                 y: (1 - observation.boundingBox.minY) * imageView.bounds.height - size.height)

            let layer = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            layer.borderWidth = 2

            imageView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }
    }
```

More info can be found here in Github repo [**iOS-11-by-Examples**](https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples)

Comment: I accepted your answer. But my problem why x = boundingBox.minX * imageView.bounds.width and y = (1 - observation.boundingBox.minY) * imageView.bounds.height - size.height)

Comment: it is because we have to scale and transform according to our original image view else it will look weird in different places.

Comment: For anyone else who is confused why you need to do `1 - observation.boundingBox.minY` it's because the coordinates of the bounding box are normalized to the dimensions of the processed image, with the origin at the image's lower-left corner. See: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317950/6942666](this)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is easy and simple way to draw boxes.**

```
let faceRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:self.faceDetection)

func faceDetection (request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation]
            else { print("unexpected result type from VNFaceObservation")
                return }
        guard observations.first != nil else {
            return
        }
        // Show the pre-processed image
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.resultImageView.subviews.forEach({ (subview) in
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            })
            for face in observations
            {
                let view = self.CreateBoxView(withColor: UIColor.red)
                view.frame = self.transformRect(fromRect: face.boundingBox, toViewRect: self.analyzedImageView)
                self.analyzedImageView.image = self.originalImageView.image
                self.resultImageView.addSubview(view)                
        }
    }
}

 //MARK - Instance Methods
func boxView(withColor : UIColor) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.borderColor = withColor.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return view
}


//Convert Vision Frame to UIKit Frame
func transformRect(fromRect: CGRect , toViewRect :UIView) -> CGRect {

    var toRect = CGRect()
    toRect.size.width = fromRect.size.width * toViewRect.frame.size.width
    toRect.size.height = fromRect.size.height * toViewRect.frame.size.height
    toRect.origin.y =  (toViewRect.frame.height) - (toViewRect.frame.height * fromRect.origin.y )
    toRect.origin.y  = toRect.origin.y -  toRect.size.height
    toRect.origin.x =  fromRect.origin.x * toViewRect.frame.size.width

    return toRect
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with text detection only showing boxes around text inside a certain area, such as a rectangle in the centre of the screen and not on text outside of the box?

Comment: what you mean by text detection only?

Comment: With vision text detection that puts a rectangle around text that it finds. I am looking to have a mask of some sort so only text in the mask area shows te boxes around it and not outside the mask.

Comment: I am not sure but, I think you can pass image part(masked) to detect the text after cropping it, so that you can detect the text within the rectangle.